# 聞いていない different meanings

Tags: translation

So I saw somewhere that 聞いていない could mean "wasn't listening", or "didn't hear anything" but if they are all in the past, wouldn't they be 聞いていなかった?

聞く is a continous action, so 聞いている would mean listening, or has listened, so thats why I'm kind of confused?

Its been a while since I learned this, so if I'm just messing something up, thx for the explanation. ありがとうございます

Comment: Did you consider accepting any of the answers to any of the questions you have asked so far before you posted this one?

Comment: @aguijonazo While I agree that not accepting answers at all leaves a sour taste and can be seen as childish or inconsiderate behavior it isn't obligatory and you shouldn't chase "green marks" as this user calls it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119198/349884). I think that if a question is good you should answer it if you can for the sake of answering it and not for a reward. Also this is probably NOT the place to talk about this and you should contact OP directly and explain why what he is doing is bad for the community and for himself.

Comment: @UriGreenberg - This OP was reminded of the guideline regarding accepting answers in their last [question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/99931/43676). I asked because I was curious whether they saw that reminder and still chose not to accept any of the answers to their previous questions, or they were still unaware of the guideline. If they choose not to accept any answers, that’s fine by me. I will still answer if I feel I can be of help. But how do you contact the OP directly?

Comment: @aguijonazo By opening a chat, like I did with you [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/99969/41223) in the last comment. Which I may also say that you kind of ignored ;) I was under the impression that you can use that to send an IM-like message to any user. Turns out I was wrong and you can only send to someone who joins https://chat.stackexchange.com/, my bad. Either way, if he's ignoring your attempts for conversation there isn't much we can do :(

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I know now to accept answers. I'm very sorry if this was causing a problem. Could you please inform me what was happening since I was not accepting answers?

Comment: @Infernoboy The biggest problem is that the system and humans think that the question is unresolved and you're still seeking better answers. People may keep visiting your question and try to help you even after you're satisfied. A low accept rate indicates users are not satisfied, and it can ultimately have a negative impact on the sustainability of the site itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a verb in the past (た形) contradicted with ～ていない?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42242/5010)